# multiple access to sql server database, one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have multiple apps running which access a sql server database. I had initially a table set aside for each app but now I was told to put everything into one table and have all apps access the database. I just want to make sure that just changing my connection string for all apps will suffice and that I do not have to make any other changes for all apps to write to one table. Will this be ok?
The apps are writing to the database table which has a unique index on one column and a auto incremented primary id key.
 I changed the stored procedures I had for each app since the connection strings were the same as they access the same database. Just want to make sure there will be no conflict issues when each tries to write to the same table.
None of the apps will be querying the table at any time except when I run manual queries myself.

Comment: What are your apps doing?  Reading data, writing data, or both?  How important is accuracy to you.  If app a is reading and app b is writing, do you need to be sure app a gets app b's update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your apps are all accessing different tables in a single database now, you'll need to modify or reconfigure the apps to all use the same table.

Changing the connection string would only work if the apps are all currently accessing tables *with the same name* in different databases or on different servers.

Alternatively, you could drop all of the other tables in the database and create views with those object names that would serve as "wrappers" around the joint table. A straight alias view doesn't generally add much overhead.

Comment: Thanks toby. I changed the stored procedures I had for each app since the connection strings were the same as they access the same database. Just want to make sure there will be no conflict issues when each tries to write to the same table

Comment: There are potential locking and/or deadlocking issues.  There are ways to manage these things, but it's a combination of experience & trial-and-error to get them resolved.  It will depend mostly on the complexity of the processes that occur *within a single transaction*, and load.